# Upload fails: "This file is too large to upload" - php.ini settings made

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, php-5.3

We are trying to upload files to a joomla instance which are aproximately are 10 MB. Strangely the upload fails with:

```
This file is too large to upload.
```

We have full access for custom php.ini settings (SuPHP) and also full access to the root server, settings:

```
output_buffering = off
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 250
max_input_time = 250
```

These settings are honoured by Joomla! as shown in the System Information within the administrative backend.

An Apache restart has been performed after changing values in php.ini.

Uploading files up to 2MB is possible (whereas even in the global php.ini the limit is set to 8MB).

Where is the sweet spot? Do we have to move to jquery solutions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the suggestion from @Michael , if you are using an editor like JCE, there's a similar setting in JCE Editor > profiles > profile > plugin parameters > file browser
(for JCE v 2.3.2.4)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are using TinyMCE 3.5.4 which seems to be connected/attached to the Media Manager. Uploading in image while creating an article therefore fails as well.

Comment: If you go to content > media manager, then to the upload file box, what does it say for the max file size, and can you upload directly from here?

Comment: @kfinto, if you go to JCE Editor > profiles > profile > plugin parameters > file browser you can set the max upload file size. If the setting is too low it can potentially cause a file upload error. Michael (below) mentions a similar setting in another location.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Media Manager, in that component's configuration is a field to set an upload size limit.  Adjust that accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes I'm referring to the Media Manager. We adjusted those settings accordingly - with restrictions (like 20MB or less) and without any restrictions. No success.

Answer (score 0):

I have just a had the same problem with a Joomla 2.5.28 installation using the Tiny MCE Editor. After several hours of trying to solve the problem, I decided to install the JCE Editor and this seems to have cured my problem.

Worth trying if you have same problem.